# How to call functions during a loading in Ionic?

Tags: function, ionic-framework, call, loading

I'm trying to enhance the sturdiness of my app. 
I want to be sure that the lists I'm using on a page are loading before accessing the form, but I don't want to fix a duration myself. I want to call the functions initializing my lists during the loading, and the loading screen to dismiss when the lists are charged.

Is that even possible in Ionic? I've searched everywhere here and on Ionic Support and it seems no one has the same issue as mine.

Answer (score 0):

call `ngOnInit()` it

`app.component` or if you are calling it your page then it is your

`.ts` file

```
ngOnInit(){
callYourFunction();
}
```

then handle loading

```
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) {}

async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Hellooo',
      duration: 2000
    });
    await loading.present();

    const { role, data } = await loading.onDidDismiss();

    console.log('Loading dismissed!');
  }
```